# Multivariate beta function and supermembranes

Tags: string-theory, branes

Similarly to the beta function being related to superstrings, is there any good reason to relate the multivariate beta function:

$$B (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\alpha_n) = B (\alpha_1+1,\alpha_2,\ldots\alpha_n)+B(\alpha_1,\alpha_2+1,\ldots\alpha_n)+\cdots+B (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\alpha_n+1) $$

via

$$ B(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\alpha_n) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1)\,\Gamma(\alpha_2) \cdots \Gamma(\alpha_n)}{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n)}  $$
with membranes or more generally p-branes (with $n=p+1$)?